# Clang compiling C++ to object file, Error: unable to interface with target machine

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, compiler-errors, clang, llvm

I'm attempting to use clang programatically to compile some C++ to an object file and I get the error "unable to interface with target machine" during the codegenaction. I'm wondering if I have missed some step or otherwise what the problem could be.

Below is the output of the program:

```
C:\Application\Debug>Application
Initializing targets
Targets initialized
clang -cc1 version 3.4 based upon LLVM 3.4svn default target i686-pc-win32
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.2\include\c++
 c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.2\include\c++\mingw32
 c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.2\include\c++\backward
 c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.2\include
 c:\mingw\include
 c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.2\include-fixed
End of search list.
error: unable to interface with target machine
1 error generated.
```

Here is my (very simple) program:

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits.h>

#include <llvm/Bitcode/ReaderWriter.h>
#include "clang/CodeGen/CodeGenAction.h"
#include "clang/Basic/DiagnosticOptions.h"
#include "clang/Driver/Compilation.h"
#include "clang/Driver/Driver.h"
#include "clang/Driver/Tool.h"
#include "clang/Frontend/CompilerInstance.h"
#include "clang/Frontend/CompilerInvocation.h"
#include "clang/Frontend/FrontendDiagnostic.h"
#include "clang/Frontend/TextDiagnosticPrinter.h"
#include "llvm/ADT/OwningPtr.h"
#include "llvm/ADT/SmallString.h"
#include "llvm/ExecutionEngine/ExecutionEngine.h"
#include "llvm/ExecutionEngine/JIT.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Module.h"
#include "llvm/IR/LLVMContext.h"
#include "llvm/Support/system_error.h"
#include "llvm/Support/Host.h"
#include "llvm/Support/ManagedStatic.h"
#include "llvm/Support/Path.h"
#include "llvm/Support/TargetSelect.h"
#include "llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h"

#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace llvm;
using namespace clang;
using namespace clang::driver;

int main(int argc, const char **argv, char * const *envp) {

    llvm::InitializeNativeTarget();

    IntrusiveRefCntPtr<DiagnosticOptions> DiagOpts = new DiagnosticOptions();
    TextDiagnosticPrinter *DiagClient =
        new TextDiagnosticPrinter(llvm::errs(), &*DiagOpts);

    IntrusiveRefCntPtr<DiagnosticIDs> DiagID(new DiagnosticIDs());
    DiagnosticsEngine Diags(DiagID, &*DiagOpts, DiagClient);

    driver::ArgStringList CCArgs;

    CCArgs.push_back("-cc1");
    CCArgs.push_back("-triple");
    CCArgs.push_back("i686-pc-win32");
    CCArgs.push_back("-emit-obj");
    CCArgs.push_back("-O3");
    CCArgs.push_back("-nostdsysteminc");
    CCArgs.push_back("-mrelax-all");
    CCArgs.push_back("-disable-free");
    CCArgs.push_back("-v");
    CCArgs.push_back("-coverage-file");
    CCArgs.push_back("test.o");
    CCArgs.push_back("-main-file-name");
    CCArgs.push_back("test.cpp");
    CCArgs.push_back("-mrelocation-model");
    CCArgs.push_back("static");
    CCArgs.push_back("-mdisable-fp-elim");
    CCArgs.push_back("-fmath-errno");
    CCArgs.push_back("-masm-verbose");
    CCArgs.push_back("-mconstructor-aliases");
    CCArgs.push_back("-target-cpu");
    CCArgs.push_back("pentium4");
    CCArgs.push_back("-internal-isystem");
CCArgs.push_back("c:\\mingw\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\4.7.2\\include\\c++");
    CCArgs.push_back("-internal-isystem");
CCArgs.push_back("c:\\mingw\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\4.7.2\\include\\c++\\mingw32");
    CCArgs.push_back("-internal-isystem");
CCArgs.push_back("c:\\mingw\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\4.7.2\\include\\c++\\backward");
    CCArgs.push_back("-internal-isystem");
CCArgs.push_back("c:\\mingw\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\4.7.2\\include");
    CCArgs.push_back("-internal-isystem");
    CCArgs.push_back("c:\\mingw\\include");
    CCArgs.push_back("-internal-isystem");
CCArgs.push_back("c:\\mingw\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\4.7.2\\include-fixed");
    CCArgs.push_back("-std=c++11");
    CCArgs.push_back("-fdeprecated-macro");
    CCArgs.push_back("-ferror-limit");
    CCArgs.push_back("19");
    CCArgs.push_back("-fmessage-length");
    CCArgs.push_back("150");
    CCArgs.push_back("-mstackrealign");
    CCArgs.push_back("-fms-extensions");
    CCArgs.push_back("-fmsc-version=1300");
    CCArgs.push_back("-fobjc-runtime=gcc");
    CCArgs.push_back("-fobjc-default-synthesize-properties");
    CCArgs.push_back("-fcxx-exceptions");
    CCArgs.push_back("-fexceptions");
    CCArgs.push_back("-fdiagnostics-show-option");
    CCArgs.push_back("-fcolor-diagnostics");
    CCArgs.push_back("-backend-option");
    CCArgs.push_back("-vectorize-loops");
    CCArgs.push_back("-x");
    CCArgs.push_back("c++");
    CCArgs.push_back("-o");
    CCArgs.push_back("test.o");
    CCArgs.push_back("test.cpp");

    OwningPtr<CompilerInvocation> CI(new CompilerInvocation);
    CompilerInvocation::CreateFromArgs(*CI,
        const_cast<const char **>(CCArgs.data()),
        const_cast<const char **>(CCArgs.data()) +
        CCArgs.size(),
        Diags);

    // Create a compiler instance to handle the actual work.
    CompilerInstance Clang;
    Clang.setInvocation(CI.take());

    // Create the compilers actual diagnostics engine.
    Clang.createDiagnostics();
    if (!Clang.hasDiagnostics())
        return 1;

    OwningPtr<CodeGenAction> Act(new EmitObjAction());
    if (!Clang.ExecuteAction(*Act))
        return 1;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you specify triple, does it mess up with what `llvm::InitializeNativeTarget();` did ?